# Whats the difference between java parameters and clarifying it within the method

Tags: java, parameters

I'm a bit new to this and had a question. So with java parameters. You can pass values to your methods so that you can do something with this value. Whats the difference between this and just doing this inside the class itself for example just using

```
 int tuna = 81
```

Comment: What do you do if you want the method to have different input, sometimes?

Comment: What do you mean by that?
Im new to this

Comment: How do you learn Java? In school or by self-teaching? If school: wait until the teacher covers that. If self-teaching: read a Java beginners book. Stackoverflow isn't meant to explain the absolute basics about programming.

Comment: @Flamealchamist You can call a method more than once, yeah? Using parameters, you can pass them a different value each time you call them.

Comment: Thank you Edward I understand this now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purpose of PHP parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587799/purpose-of-php-parameters)

Comment: Not at all i was asking about java not PHP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Parameters allows a method to have more flexibility. Sometimes it is necessary to run a method but with different arguments, this is where parameters become handy.

**For Example (Clarifying):**

```
public void calcTotal()
{
    int firstNum= 1;
    int secondNum=2;

    System.out.println(firstNum+secondNum);

    //when we run calcTotal()
    //output= 3

}
```

This method would correctly print the sum of the two numbers. However, this method will only allow us to print the sum of 1+2. **What happens when we want to find the sum of another set of two integers i.e 5 & 6?**

**Would we give this task to another method by copying the first one and changing the values of `firstNum` & `secondNum`?**

```
public void calcTotal()
{
    int firstNum= 5;
    int secondNum=6;

    System.out.println(firstNum+secondNum);

    //when we run calcTotal()
    //output= 3
}
```

**The Answer is NO.**

By allowing a method to take arguments... We can...

```
public void calcTotal(int firstNum, int secondNum)
{
    System.out.println(firstNum+secondNum);
}
```

With a method that can take arguments... We can...

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    calcTotal(1,2); //output 3
    calcTotal(5,6); //11
    calcTotal(6,7); //12
}
```

calculate the sum of different pairs of integers without creating another method for each set of integers.